# Laravel user post image upload error

Tags: image, laravel, post, upload

I have error while i am uploading Post Image I can save picture on my computer but in my database filename is distorted.

Here is my `PostsController`

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user, Image $image)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);


    if( $request->hasFile('image') ) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Image::make($image)->save( public_path('uploads/images/' . $filename ) );
    }

    $image = $filename;

    auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(request(['body', 'image'])));

    return redirect('/');
}
```

[image: filename is wrong]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to insert the wrong variable into your database table. So, improve your code like this:

```
auth()->user()->publish(
    new Post(['photo' => request('body'), 'image' => $image])
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your great help
I just have one more issue regarding post user name and avatar person who posted.